# Sniffing devices in a serial topology

Tags: penetration-test, man-in-the-middle, sniffing, fuzzing, voip

I have the following setup:

```
PBX Server -> Internet -> LAN -> IP Phone -> Workstation (PC)
```

Which means that my computer is connected to the LAN, through a Dual Ethernet card on the IP Phone.

I would like to analyze traffic between my IP Phone and the LAN during it's normal operations (incoming / outgoing calls, text messages, web interface actions...) which are all handled by communication with the PBX.

The answer I look for would:

- Be as much to the right part of the above chain as possible. Directly dumping from my workstation would be the most prefered if there's a way, dumping from the PBX server the least,
- Optionally provide extensibility for traffic injection.

I have full physical and administrative control over the entire setup, so putting a server somewhere in between is an option.